# Access object path in plain text or array with props

Tags: javascript, performance

Consider the bellow object and a path to a value stored inside object:

```
var obj = { a: 1, b: { a: { x: 2 }, b: 3 }, c: 4 }
var path = ["b", "a", "x"];
```

What is the best way (best performance) to get the content in object path?

**Using eval()**

```
path = ["obj"].concat(path);
var value = eval(path.join("."));
```

**Looping**

```
var _obj = obj;
for(key in path) {
    _obj = _obj[path[key]];
}
var value = _obj;
```

Is there any other better way to store and query a object complex?

Comment: Benchmark it and test for yourself.

Comment: I have benchmarked it and I get a better performance in case of eval() but I see a lot of warning about eval() use, one of is about performance break in modern javascript engines

Comment: Better performance for `eval` means there is something wrong with your benchmark.

Comment: I'm using `console.time() `

Comment: What you have simply an object. It has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: please [have a look](https://jsperf.com/deep-acces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the path and use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for the object.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return (o || {})[k];
    }, object);
}

var obj = { a: 1, b: { a: { x: 2 }, b: 3 }, c: 4 }
    path = ["b", "a", "x"];

console.log(getValue(obj, path));
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursive version:

```js
function getPath(obj, [head, ...tail]) {
  return !obj ? null : !head ? obj : getPath(obj[head], tail);
}

var obj = { a: 1, b: { a: { x: 2 }, b: 3 }, c: 4 };
var path = ["b", "a", "x"];

console.log(getPath(obj, path));
```

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is slow. Looping is fast, so I would suggest that you use the...

### Boring Version:

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: { a: { x: 2 }, b: 3 }, c: 4 }
var path = ["b", "a", "x"];

function getDeep(object, path) {
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    if (object == null) return
    object = object[path[i]]
  }
  return object
}

console.log(getDeep(obj, path)) //=> 2
```

Comment: I don't like `if (object == null)` - you would be better off with a test like `if( !object.hasOwnProperty(path[i])) throw new Error("Sensible error message here");`

Comment: I considered doing as much, and feel free to do so yourself, but I thought it most mimicked JavaScript's default behavior which is to return `undefined` when a property access fails, rather than throw an error. I wanted the `getDeep` function to *feel* like a single property access.

Comment: `var obj = {a:1}; alert(obj.b.deeper);` throws an error ;)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of how multiple property accesses usually work; like I said I wanted the method to feel like a single access. Just a personal choice so feel free to adjust the method as you see fit!

Answer (score 1):

If you know for shure that object you are pasing have that properties you should use this:

```js
const createAccesor = path => {
    let func = 'return obj'
    for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
        func += `['${path[i]}']`
    }
    return Function('obj', func)
}
const obj = { a: 1, b: { a: { x: 2 }, b: 3 }, c: 4 }
const acces = createAccesor(['b', 'a', 'x'])
console.log(acces(obj))
```

Here is **[speed test](https://jsperf.com/deep-acces)**.
Problem with this solution is that it will throw while object does not contain prop you specify in path.

Or use less efficient accesor like this:

```js
const createAccesor = path => {
    let func = 'let temp=obj;'
    for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
        func += `if(temp=temp['${path[i]}'])`
    }
    func += ';return temp'
    return Function('obj', func)
}
const obj = { a: 1, b: { a: { x: 2 }, b: 3 }, c: 4 }
const acces = createAccesor(['b', 'n', 'x', 'n'])
const acces2 = createAccesor(['b', 'a', 'x'])
console.log(acces(obj))
console.log(acces2(obj))
```

Note that this speeds up only when you have multiple objects to 'query' or use this many times, else you won't gain any speed.

Problem with `eval` is that if it apears inside function it can't be optimizeb by js engine.

You can also create 'syntax' for yourself for example instead of pasing `array` you can pass 'acces string' like so `'b->a->x'` or `'b.a.x'` and then just call split in function with /->/g or '.' it won't affect your acces spead and it's just nicer looking :D and you dont have to write ,' all the time